# When did Stabler meet Benson's Son, Noah

Tags: law-and-order-svu

I have just finished watching [Law & Order: Special Victims Unit 23x20](https://www.tvmaze.com/episodes/2303795/law-order-special-victims-unit-23x20-did-you-believe-in-miracles) and the episode ends with Benson and Noah celebrating Mother's Day

[image]

I was surprised to find out that [Benson has introduced Stabler to Noah](https://tvline.com/2022/05/05/law-and-order-recap-seaosn-23-episode-20-stabler-meets-noah/#more-1234826989)

[image]

When did that happen? The article mentions that it happened on Thursday's episode, but I can't seem to find such a scene? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scene seems to have been cut from streaming services, probably for time.

TV Line (same source as original link)

> Fans who love the case-of-the-week aspect of the show likely saw the scene as unnecessary. Fans who desperately want Stabler and Benson to be a romantic couple likely saw the scene as a step in the right direction.
>
> And fans who watched the episode on Hulu on Friday… didn’t see the scene at all.
>
> The Benson/Stabler meet-up was a bridge between SVU and the crossover episode of Law & Order: Organized Crime that followed. (Read our SVU recap here and our OC recap here.) Viewers who watched the live broadcast witnessed Olivia’s Mother’s Day get interrupted by a work call that caused her to ask Elliot whether he knew a cop named Jessie Santos, and then take Noah home quickly. In the next scene — and without a commercial break between the episodes — Liv was at Organized Crime to propose that SVU and OC work together to find the kidnapped daughter of Santos, an NYPD officer who happened to be part of the police corruption ring Elliot had been investigating.
>
> But those who streamed the crossover Friday saw SVU end with Noah hugging his mom at brunch, and Organized Crime begin with Benson visiting OC Bureau headquarters to suggest the joint investigation — though a snippet of the post-brunch street scene appears at the end of the “Previously on…” segment at the top of the hour.
>
> **We’re hearing that the editing could have happened as a result of fitting the episodes to the streaming format, as well as to avoid potential SVU viewers’ confusion regarding Benson mentioning a cop/case that wouldn’t be resolved on that show**